# How to fix layout for 5.5+ inches?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I've this problem. I've publish my app on the Play Store, and I see the first problem: in the devices with 5.7 inches some text "exploded" and it goes out the card, like this example:[image]

now I'd like to know how to fix this problem. I think that a good way is to create a layout-sw400dp file for any xml and adapt the layout, but is it really work? Or there are other ways to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a different xml file and put it in layout-sw400dp , it will work well. And the second option is you can use constraintLayout which will adapt the layout according to the screen sizes. ConstraintLayout helps you to make responsive layouts. You can learn constraintLayout from here

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html